# Problem with propietary nvidia driver and glmark2

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Running Xubuntu 15.04 AMD64 on a HP Touchsmart IQ522es, Core 2 Duo T6400, 4GB RAM and nvidia GeForce 9300M GS video card. (which is a quite old All-in-one computer)

I have enabled nvidia binary driver from Software and Updates > additional drivers, -version 340.76 (propietary - tested), then (PC froze when logging out and had to do a hard reset) rebooted.

Then I wanted to test the performance against the open source nouveau driver, which I succesfully tested with glmark2 before installing the propietary driver.

When I tried to run **glmark2** (which worked fine with nouveau) I was presented this error message:

```
fonewn@Ubuntu-Touchsmart-IQ522es:~$ glmark2
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-version.c: 224: _dl_check_map_versions: Assertion `needed != ((void *)0)' failed!
```

What can I do? Does this mean that proper, hardware enabled, OpenGL is not running on my system?

What other info should I give you guys in order to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a known bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-319/+bug/1248642

It says a solution has been release but I still get the error. I will post again as soon as I am able to test what they propose or just my system gets fixed by an update.